# see both, text, cursors with two frames in emacs

Tags: emacs

In `emacs` I can open two frames (Windows). That can view the some edit buffer. I can use this so that two people can edit a file at the same time. This is useful for remote teaching. (I am teaching programming, so no use using collaborative work processors. And must be [Free-Software](https://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software).)

Is there a way to configure it so that we can both see each others text cursor?
This would be useful for pointing, and to see what is about to be edited.

Comment: For collaborative editing, I usually gesture vaguely toward projects designed for that sort of thing rather than bolting it onto another tool.  There are options like Firepad, Google Docs, PrimaryPad, and others.

Comment: Is that the mouse cursor or the text cursor (which Emacs calls point)? Are you the two frames on different X displays? @DopeGhoti Others including [Rudel](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/rudel.html)?

Comment: Quite probably, yes.  `emacs` truly is a versatile OS that just needs a good text editor! (:

Comment: I have updated question to say which cursor, and why it needs to be emacs.